# Automatic cash dispenser

Tags: java

apprentice in Java I try to recreate an automatic cash dispenser. Up to there everything goes well, my class has to take unitarian tests, but he(it) fails in 2 on 16 there. I do not see where from the error can come. Can anybody help me to reveal it and to help me possibly? Here is the code :

```
public class DABiP {
int nbBillet100;
int nbBillet50;
int nbBillet20 ;
int nbBillet10 ; 
int nbPiece2; 
int nbPiece1; 

//Constructeur privÃ©
private DABiP(int b10, int b5, int b2, int b1, int p2, int p1){
    nbBillet100 = b10;
    nbBillet50  = b5;
    nbBillet20  = b2;
    nbBillet10  = b1;
    nbPiece2    = p2;
    nbPiece1    = p1;
}
//DABiP initialisÃ© avec 100 unitÃ©s de chaque, soit 18300euros
public DABiP(){
    this(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100);
}

/************************************************************
* SEULES LES METHODES QUI SUIVENT DOIVENT ETRE MODIFIEES
*************************************************************/

//Calculer le montant restant dans le DABiP
public int calculerMontantRestantDansDABiP(){
    int a;

    a = nbBillet100 * 100 + nbBillet50 * 50 + nbBillet20 * 20 + nbBillet10 * 10 + nbPiece2 * 2 + nbPiece1 * 1;

    return a;
}
//Retirer une somme d'argent du DABiP
public boolean retrait(int somme){

    int x = 0;

    if(somme > calculerMontantRestantDansDABiP()) {
        return false;   
    }
    else if(somme < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    else{
        if(somme/100 > 1){
            x = somme/100;
            if(nbBillet100 - x >= 0){
                nbBillet100 = nbBillet100 - x;
                somme = somme - 100 * x;
            }
            else {
                x = nbBillet100;
                nbBillet100 = 0;
                somme = somme - 100 * x;
            }
        }

        if(somme/50 > 1){
            x = somme/50;
            if(nbBillet50 - x >= 0){
                nbBillet50 = nbBillet50 - x;
                somme = somme - 50 * x;
            }
            else{
                x = nbBillet50;
                nbBillet50 = 0;
                somme = somme - 50 * x;
            }
        }

        if(somme/20 > 1){
            x  = somme/20;
            if(nbBillet20 - x >= 0){
                nbBillet20 = nbBillet20 - x;
                somme = somme - 20 * x;
            }
            else{
                x = nbBillet20;
                nbBillet20 = 0;
                somme = somme - 20 * x;
            }
        }

        if(somme/10 > 1){
            x = somme/10;
            if(nbBillet10 - x >= 0){
                nbBillet10 = nbBillet10 - x;
                somme = somme - 10 * x;
            }
            else{
                x = nbBillet10;
                nbBillet10 = 0;
                somme = somme - 10 * x;
            }
        }

        if(somme/2 > 1){
            x = somme/2;
            if(nbPiece2 - x >= 0){
                nbPiece2 = nbPiece2 - x;
                somme = somme - 2 * x;
            }
            else{
                x = nbPiece2;
                nbPiece2 = 0;
                somme = somme - 2 * x;
            }
        }

        if(somme >= 1){
            x = somme;
            if(nbPiece1 - x >= 0){
                nbPiece1 = nbPiece1 - x;
                somme = somme - x;
            }
            else{
                x = nbPiece1;
                nbPiece1 = 0;
                somme = somme - x;
            }
            }
    return true;
    }

}
```

}

my test :

```
public class Notation {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    DABiP dab;
    double note     = 0;
    double score    = 0;

    //Test 1
    System.out.print("Test 01: ");
    dab         = new DABiP();
    if(dab.calculerMontantRestantDansDABiP() == 18300){
        score++;
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("non");
    }

    //Test 2
    System.out.print("Test 02: ");
    dab.nbBillet100 = 95;
    if(dab.calculerMontantRestantDansDABiP() == 17800){
        score++;
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("non");
    }

    //Test 3
    System.out.print("Test 03: ");
    dab.nbBillet50  = 97;
    dab.nbPiece2    = 96;
    dab.nbPiece1    = 97;
    if(dab.calculerMontantRestantDansDABiP() == 17639){
        score++;
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("non");
    }

    //Test 4
    System.out.print("Test 04: ");
    int tab[] = {100, 50, 20, 10, 2, 1};
    int p = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        int rand = tab[(int)(Math.random()*100)%tab.length];
        int nb = (int)(Math.random()*100)%6;
        p += (rand==100?100*nb:0);
        p += (rand==50?50*nb:0);
        p += (rand==20?20*nb:0);
        p += (rand==10?10*nb:0);
        p += (rand==2?2*nb:0);
        p += (rand==1?1*nb:0);
        dab.nbBillet100-=(rand==100?nb:0);
        dab.nbBillet50-=(rand==50?nb:0);
        dab.nbBillet20-=(rand==20?nb:0);
        dab.nbBillet10-=(rand==10?nb:0);
        dab.nbPiece2-=(rand==2?nb:0);
        dab.nbPiece1-=(rand==1?nb:0);
    }
    if(dab.calculerMontantRestantDansDABiP() == 17639-p){
        score++;
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("non");
    }

    //Test 5
    System.out.print("Test 05: ");
    dab.nbBillet100 = 0;
    dab.nbBillet50  = 0;
    dab.nbBillet20  = 0;
    dab.nbBillet10  = 0;
    dab.nbPiece2    = 0;
    dab.nbPiece1    = 0;
    if(dab.calculerMontantRestantDansDABiP() == 0){
        score++;
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("non");
    }

    //Test 6
    System.out.print("Test 06: ");
    dab = new DABiP();
    boolean r = dab.retrait(0);
    if(r && dab.nbBillet100 == 100 && dab.nbBillet50 == 100 && dab.nbBillet20 == 100 && dab.nbBillet10 == 100 && dab.nbPiece2 == 100 && dab.nbPiece1 == 100){
        score++;
        System.out.println("ok");

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("non");
    }

    //Test 7
    System.out.print("Test 07: ");
    dab = new DABiP();
    r = dab.retrait(40);
    if(r && dab.nbBillet100 == 100 && dab.nbBillet50 == 100 && dab.nbBillet20 == 98 && dab.nbBillet10 == 100 && dab.nbPiece2 == 100 && dab.nbPiece1 == 100){
        score++;
        System.out.println("ok");

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("non");
    }

    //Test 8
    System.out.print("Test 08: ");
    dab = new DABiP();
    r = dab.retrait(367);
    if(r && dab.nbBillet100 == 97 && dab.nbBillet50 == 99 && dab.nbBillet20 == 100 && dab.nbBillet10 == 99 && dab.nbPiece2 == 97 && dab.nbPiece1 == 99){
        score++;
        System.out.println("ok");

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("non");
    }

    //Test 9
    System.out.print("Test 09: ");
    dab = new DABiP();
    r = dab.retrait(18300);
    if(r && dab.nbBillet100 == 0 && dab.nbBillet50 == 0 && dab.nbBillet20 == 0 && dab.nbBillet10 == 0 && dab.nbPiece2 == 0 && dab.nbPiece1 == 0){
        score++;
        System.out.println("ok");

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("non");
    }

    //Test 10
    System.out.print("Test 10: ");
    dab = new DABiP();
    r = dab.retrait(18301);
    if(!r && dab.nbBillet100 == 100 && dab.nbBillet50 == 100 && dab.nbBillet20 == 100 && dab.nbBillet10 == 100 && dab.nbPiece2 == 100 && dab.nbPiece1 == 100){
        score++;
        System.out.println("ok");

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("non");
    }

    //Test 11
    System.out.print("Test 11: ");
    dab = new DABiP();
    r = dab.retrait(19634);
    if(!r && dab.nbBillet100 == 100 && dab.nbBillet50 == 100 && dab.nbBillet20 == 100 && dab.nbBillet10 == 100 && dab.nbPiece2 == 100 && dab.nbPiece1 == 100){
        score++;
        System.out.println("ok");

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("non");
    }

    //Test 12
    System.out.print("Test 12: ");
    dab = new DABiP();
    dab.nbBillet100 = 2;
    r = dab.retrait(300);
    if(r && dab.nbBillet100 == 0 && dab.nbBillet50 == 98 && dab.nbBillet20 == 100 && dab.nbBillet10 == 100 && dab.nbPiece2 == 100 && dab.nbPiece1 == 100){
        score+=2;
        System.out.println("ok");

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("non");
    }

    //Test 13
    System.out.print("Test 13: ");
    dab = new DABiP();
    dab.nbBillet100 = 2;
    dab.nbBillet50  = 1;
    dab.nbBillet20  = 5;
    dab.nbBillet10  = 6;
    dab.nbPiece2    = 50;
    r = dab.retrait(407);
    if(r && dab.nbBillet100 == 0 && dab.nbBillet50 == 0 && dab.nbBillet20 == 0 && dab.nbBillet10 == 1 && dab.nbPiece2 == 47 && dab.nbPiece1 == 99){
        score+=2;
        System.out.println("ok");

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("non");
    }

    //Test 14
    System.out.print("Test 14: ");
    dab = new DABiP();
    dab.nbBillet100 = 0;
    dab.nbBillet50  = 0;
    dab.nbBillet20  = 0;
    dab.nbBillet10  = 0;
    dab.nbPiece2    = 0;

    r = dab.retrait(57);
    if(r && dab.nbBillet100 == 0 && dab.nbBillet50 == 0 && dab.nbBillet20 == 0 && dab.nbBillet10 == 0 && dab.nbPiece2 == 0 && dab.nbPiece1 == 43){
        score+=2;
        System.out.println("ok");

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("non");
    }

    //Test 15
    System.out.print("Test 15: ");
    dab = new DABiP();
    r = dab.retrait(-1634);
    if(!r && dab.nbBillet100 == 100 && dab.nbBillet50 == 100 && dab.nbBillet20 == 100 && dab.nbBillet10 == 100 && dab.nbPiece2 == 100 && dab.nbPiece1 == 100){
        score++;
        System.out.println("ok");

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("non");
    }

    //Test 16
    System.out.print("Test 16: ");
    dab = new DABiP();
    dab.nbBillet100 = 5;
    dab.nbBillet50 = 0;
    dab.nbBillet20 = 0;
    dab.nbBillet10 = 0;
    dab.nbPiece2 = 0;
    dab.nbPiece1 = 5;
    r = dab.retrait(12);
    if(!r && dab.nbBillet100 == 5 && dab.nbBillet50 == 0 && dab.nbBillet20 == 0 && dab.nbBillet10 == 0 && dab.nbPiece2 == 0 && dab.nbPiece1 == 5) {
        score+=2;
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("non");
    }


    /**
     * NOTATION
     */

    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    System.out.println("Note: "+score+"/20");


}
```

}

Sorry for my bad english i'm french

Comment: Run your code step-by-step under debugger and you should see.

Comment: If you call with e.g. `somme = 165`, then I'd expect a 100 bill, but `somme / 100 > 1` is false, because `somme / 100` is **equal** to `1`.

Comment: When you dispense cash, shouldn't the program actually show *what* cash was dispensed?

Comment: Dispense some cash to me and I'll help.

Answer (score 1):

To fix Test 8, as Andreas pointed out, you need to change all of these comparisons where you use **greater than** (>):

```
if(somme/100 > 1){ ...
```

to use **greater than or equal to** (>=) instead:

```
if(somme/100 >= 1){ ...
```

When I made this change and ran your code again, Test 8 passed. This is because when `somme` is, say, 67, and you reach the code block for dispensing 50 pieces, `somme/50` is an **int** value so the decimal place gets chopped off, and it equals 1. 1 is not greater than 1, so your if statement gets skipped. Thank you to Andreas for pointing this out.

About Test 16 - the way your code is written, if the machine does not have enough money of a certain denomination - for example, if it needs to give out 12 ones, but it only has 5 ones - the machine will give out all the money it has even if that was not enough, and then it finishes all of the code and returns **true** anyway.

I think you might want to insert a final check if there didn't turn out to be enough money, and return **false** instead if there was not quite enough money. I would change this:

```
if(somme >= 1){
        x = somme;
        if(nbPiece1 - x >= 0){
            nbPiece1 = nbPiece1 - x;
            somme = somme - x;
        }
        else{
            x = nbPiece1;
            nbPiece1 = 0;
            somme = somme - x;
        }
    }
```

To this:

```
if(somme >= 1){
            x = somme;
            if(nbPiece1 - x >= 0){
                nbPiece1 = nbPiece1 - x;
                somme = somme - x;
            }
            else{
                x = nbPiece1;
                nbPiece1 = 0;
                somme = somme - x;

                // ADD A CHECK HERE
                if(somme > 0){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Also, your Test 16 thinks that the number of 1's left in the machine should be 5, but remember that you wrote your code to give out all the money it can. The actual number of 1's left will be 0, because it tried to give them out even though there were not enough. This seems like what you wanted it to do, so maybe you just wrote Test 16 wrong.

I hope that this answer was helpful. If you have other issues or questions, let us know and we'll take a look for you.

Et si vous voulez ma réponse en français, je peux essayer - mais mon français n'est pas très bien! (If you want this in French I can try, but my French isn't great.)